# D3js Graph bundle group

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi based on [GerHobbelt/3071239](http://bl.ocks.org/GerHobbelt/3104394) i try to add a mouseover event on link to show value of it, so in a first time i try to change stroke color and width like this :

```
hlink.exit().remove();
      hlink.enter().append("path")
          .attr("class", "hlink") 
          .on("mouseover", function() { d3.select(this).style("stroke", "#555555").attr("stroke-opacity", "1.0").attr("stroke-width","4");})
            .on("mouseout", function() { d3.select(this).style("stroke", "#ccc").attr("stroke-opacity", "1.0").attr("stroke-width","1") });
```

But it doesn't work someone hava any idea what can resolve it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

"Stroke" is an attribute rather than a style, so use the `.attr()` method instead of the `.style()` method:

```
hlink.exit().remove();
      hlink.enter().append("path")
          .attr("class", "hlink") 
          .on("mouseover", function() { d3.select(this).attr("stroke", "#555555").attr("stroke-opacity", "1.0").attr("stroke-width","4");})
            .on("mouseout", function() { d3.select(this).attr("stroke", "#ccc").attr("stroke-opacity", "1.0").attr("stroke-width","1") });
```

Comment: Thank for you answer but i think that the problem is in the mouseover event because when i try  .on("mouseover", function() { console.log("test")}) nothing is happen